# How to change and delete a variable in stack?

Tags: c++

1. Create a record to store the following information:

   - owner code
   - car number,
   - car model,
   - Release date,
   - date of registration.
2. Provide the ability to add, modify and delete records and displays
   data to the screen. Use the stack to store data.
3. Get a list of license plates and car brands registered in November and December
   last year.
4. Find the average age for each of the encountered car brands.
5. Find the "age" up to the year of each of the cars registered in
   February and March of the current year.

It is necessary that the record I need is deleted and edited (second, fifth, etc.). But it happens to only with the last record added. How to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct DATE
{
    int number;
    int month;
    int year;
};
struct informations
{
    char code[10];
    char number_car[10];
    char mark[10];
    DATE release;
    DATE registration;
    informations* next;  

} typedef Informations;

Informations* top = nullptr; 

void push()
{
    Informations* ptr = new Informations;  

    cin.get();
    cout << "Enter the code owner: ";
    cin.getline(ptr->code, 10); 
    cout << "Enter the number of the car: ";
    cin.getline(ptr->number_car, 10);
    cout << "Enter the mark of the car: ";
    cin.getline(ptr->mark, 10);

    cout << "Enter the date of release: " << endl;
    do {
        cout << "number: ";
        cin >> ptr->release.number;
    } while ((ptr->release.number > 31) || (ptr->release.number <= 0));
    do {
        cout << "month: ";
        cin >> ptr->release.month;
    } while ((ptr->release.month > 12) || (ptr->release.month <= 0)); 
    do {
        cout << "year: ";
        cin >> ptr->release.year;
    } while ((ptr->release.year > 2019) || (ptr->release.year <= 1980));  

    cout << "Enter the date of registration: " << endl;
    do {
        cout << "number: ";
        cin >> ptr->registration.number;
    } while ((ptr->registration.number > 31) || (ptr->registration.number <= 0));
    do {
        cout << "month: ";
        cin >> ptr->registration.month;
    } while ((ptr->registration.month > 12) || (ptr->registration.month <= 0));
    do {
        cout << "year: ";
        cin >> ptr->registration.year;
    } while ((ptr->registration.year > 2019) || (ptr->registration.year <= 1980)); 
    cout << endl;

    ptr->next = top; 
    top = ptr; 
}

void change()
{
    cin.get();
    cout << "Enter the code owner: ";
    cin.getline(top->code, 10);
    cout << "Enter the number of the car: ";
    cin.getline(top->number_car, 10);
    cout << "Enter the mark of the car: ";
    cin.getline(top->mark, 10);

    cout << "Enter the date of release:" << endl;
    do {
        cout << "number: ";
        cin >> top->release.number;
    } while ((top->release.number > 31) || (top->release.number <= 0));
    do {
        cout << "month: ";
        cin >> top->release.month;
    } while ((top->release.month > 12) || (top->release.month <= 0));
    do {
        cout << "year: ";
        cin >> top->release.year;
    } while ((top->release.year > 2019) || (top->release.year <= 1980));

    cout << "Enter the date of registration: " << endl;
    do {
        cout << "number: ";
        cin >> top->registration.number;
    } while ((top->registration.number > 31) || (top->registration.number <= 0));
    do {
        cout << "month: ";
        cin >> top->registration.month;
    } while ((top->registration.month > 12) || (top->registration.month <= 0));
    do {
        cout << "year: ";
        cin >> top->registration.year;
    } while ((top->registration.year > 2019) || (top->registration.year <= 1980));
    cout << endl;
}


void pop() 
{
    auto bad = top;  
    top = top->next;
    delete bad;
}

void show_stack() 
{
    int i = 0;
    cout << endl;
    Informations* ptr = top;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        i++;
        cout << "           " << i << endl;
        cout << "The code owner: " << ptr->code << endl;
        cout << "The number of the car: " << ptr->number_car << endl;
        cout << "The mark of the car: " << ptr->mark << endl;
        cout << "The date of release:\nnumber:\t\t\t\t" << ptr->release.number << endl;
        cout << "month:\t\t\t\t" << ptr->release.month << endl;                        
        cout << "year:\t\t\t\t" << ptr->release.year << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "The date of registration:\nnumber:\t\t\t\t" << ptr->registration.number << endl;
        cout << "month:\t\t\t\t" << ptr->registration.month << endl;
        cout << "year:\t\t\t\t" << ptr->registration.year << endl;
        cout << endl;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

void November_and_December()  
{
    Informations* ptr = top;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        if ((ptr->registration.month == 11) || (ptr->registration.month == 12))
        {
            if (ptr->registration.year == 2018)
            {
                cout << "The number of the car: " << ptr->number_car << endl;
                cout << "The mark of the car: " << ptr->mark << endl;
                cout << endl;
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
        }
        else cout << endl;
    }
}

void Average_age()
{
    Informations* ptr = top;
    int i = 0;
    int averageyear = 0;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        i++;
        averageyear += ptr->release.year;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    double average = averageyear / i;
    cout << average << endl;

}

void February_and_March()   
{
    int vozrast;
    Informations* ptr = top;
    while (ptr != NULL)

    {
        if (((ptr->registration.month == 2) || (ptr->registration.month == 3)) && (ptr->registration.year == 2019)) 
        {
            vozrast = (ptr->registration.year) - (ptr->release.year); 

            if ((ptr->registration.month) < (ptr->release.month)) 
            {
                vozrast = vozrast - 1;
                cout << "Age of car: " << vozrast << endl;
                cout << "The mark of the car: " << ptr->mark << endl;
                cout << endl;
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }


            else if ((ptr->registration.month) == (ptr->release.month))
            {
                if ((ptr->registration.number) < (ptr->release.number))
                {
                    vozrast = vozrast - 1;
                    cout << "Age of car: " << vozrast << endl;
                    cout << "The mark of the car: " << ptr->mark << endl;
                    cout << endl;
                    ptr = ptr->next;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Age of car: " << vozrast << endl;
                    cout << "The mark of the car: " << ptr->mark << endl;
                    cout << endl;
                    ptr = ptr->next;
                }
            }

        }
        else {
            cout << "Age of car: " << vozrast << endl;
            cout << "The mark of the car: " << ptr->mark << endl;
            cout << endl;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int l;
    do
    {
        cout << "--------------------------------------";
        cout << endl;
        cout << " 1)Enter " << endl << " 2)Change " << endl << " 3)Delete " << endl << " 4)Show " << endl << " 5)November and December " << endl << " 6)Average age" << endl << " 7)February and March" << endl << " 8)Exit " << endl;
        cin >> l;
        switch (l)
        {
        case 1:push(); break;
        case 2: {
            if (top != NULL) change(); break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            if (top != NULL) pop(); break;
        }
        case 4:   show_stack(); break;
        case 5:
        {
            if (top != NULL) November_and_December(); break;
        }

        case 6: if (top != NULL) Average_age(); break;

        case 7:
        {
            if (top != NULL) February_and_March(); break;
        }

        default:break;
        }
    } while (l != 8);
}
```

Comment: You fix it by adding code to select a record (for example by asking for a license code and finding the `informations` object that has that license code) instead of changing/deleting the `top` element.

Comment: why do you use a stack when you need to access n-th element?

Comment: A `std::vector<Informations>` may be better than a `stack`. (but it your case your "stack" is basically a *linked-list* where you are chaining from the head (top) node.) So to delete, you can delete any node in the list.

Comment: A stack is a very unsuitable structure for this problem. (It's also not clear at all what "the stack" in the problem description refers to.)

Answer (score 3):

Since your collection of data is actually a *linked-list* which is being treated as a *stack* by only operating on the `top` (head) node, you can simply provide the `code` and `number` to identify a unique car in the list and delete that node from your list. Since both `code` and `number` members are held as type `char *`, you can use `strcmp` to compare the values. To locate and delete an individual node from the list you can use:

```
void del_car (const char *code, const char *number)
{
    Informations **ppn = &top,      /* pointer to pointer to top node */
                  *pn = top;        /* pointer to top node */

    while (pn) {                    /* iterate over each car */
        /* compare with code and number to delete */
        if (strcmp(pn->code, code) == 0 && strcmp(pn->number, number) == 0) {
            *ppn = pn->next;        /* set node at current address to next */
            delete pn;              /* delete current node */
            return;
        }
        ppn = &pn->next;            /* advances address of current to next */
        pn = pn->next;              /* advance current to next */
    }

    fputs ("car not found.\n", stderr);     /* warn if no match found */
}
```

However, the use of `new/delete` and basic types of `char *` instead of using the current STL `std::vector` and `std::string`, is about a decade or more out of date. (there is nothing wrong with knowing how to use `new/delete` and fundamental types -- there is a lot of legacy code out there, but for new code, you are much better off letting the containers manage the memory for you)

Give it a try and let me know if you have further questions. See [Linus on Understand Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/) for understanding why it is advantageous to iterate using both a pointer to `top` (a *pointer-to-pointer*) and the pointer `top` to delete the node in the list.