# Why does reordering of linked list fail?

Tags: c++, data-structures, singly-linked-list

In this code I'm trying to modify the list such that the even numbers appear first in the list and odd numbers appear last in the list, using the evenOdd() function.
But the expected output is not obtained, help me out.

**Expected Output :**

Before Ordering :
  1 -->   2 -->   3 -->   4 -->   5 -->   6 -->   7 --> NULL
After Ordering :
 2 -->   4 -->   6 -->   1 -->   3 -->   5 -->   7 --> NULL

**Actual Output:**

1 -->   2 -->   3 -->   4 -->   5 -->   6 -->   7 --> NULL

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

void addEnd(Node **head, int val)
{
    Node *temp=*head;
    Node *newnode=new Node();
    newnode->data=val;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    if(*head == NULL) {*head = newnode; return;}
    while(temp->next!=NULL) {temp=temp->next;}
    temp->next=newnode;
}

void deleteKey(Node **head,int val)
{
    Node *temp=*head;
    Node* prev;
    if(temp!=NULL and temp->data == val)
    {
        *head = temp->next;
        delete temp;
        return;
    }
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data == val) {prev = temp; break;}
        prev=temp;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(temp->data != val) {cout<<"NO SUCH VAlUES"; return;}
    prev->next=temp->next;
}

void evenOdd(Node **head)
{
    Node *temp = *head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data%2 == 1)
        {addEnd(*(&head),temp->data); deleteKey(*(&head),temp->data);}
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void printList(Node *node)
{
    while(node!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"  "<<node->data<<" --> ";
        node=node->next;
    }
    cout<<"NULL";
}

int main()
{
    Node *head = NULL;
    addEnd(&head,1);
    addEnd(&head,2);
    addEnd(&head,3);
    addEnd(&head,4);
    addEnd(&head,5);
    addEnd(&head,6);
    addEnd(&head,7);
    cout<<"Before Ordering :\n";
    printList(head);
    evenOdd(&head);
    cout<<"After Ordering :\n";
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this combination

```
if(temp->data%2 == 1)
```

and

```
deleteKey(*(&head),temp->data);
```

you are deleting the node you are currently looking at. Including an actual

```
delete temp;
```

inside `deleteKey`.

But then you access the memory you just deleted, here

```
temp = temp->next;
```

inside `evenOdd`.

After that, all bets are off.

But the observed problem is caused here inside `deleteKey` :

```
prev->next=temp->next;
```

it uses `prev` with a value identical to `temp`.
I.e. it does not change temp and especially not the pointer which points to temp.
To achieve that, you need to keep track of the pointer pointing to the node you want to delete, and change THAT.
The naming of your variables indicates that you know the concept and try to do it here

```
{prev = temp; break;}
```

But obviously that cannot retrieve the pointer.
You need to update that `prev` all the way along and then something like this needs to be inside your delete code

```
{prev->next = temp->next; break;} /* prev->next currently points to temp, but prev!= temp */
/* update the "next" pointing to current node so that it points to the next one */
```

You might find this other of my answers useful for anaylsing this kind of poitner problems:
[Tricks to analyse pointer and pointer-to-pointer structures in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097696/tricks-to-analyse-pointer-and-pointer-to-pointer-structures-in-c/59097858#59097858)

Comment: Or simplify the delete considerably by using the address of the node [linked list delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645747/how-to-change-and-delete-a-variable-in-stack/59646683#59646683). That eliminates the need to track the `prev` pointer completely.

Answer (score 0):

in the evenOdd function `temp` is pointing to the node inserted at the back whereas it should be pointing to the 2,3,4 rd node as per the iteration . so when you do temp = temp->next,it is overflowing.

Comment: How?, I'm just adding the data of the temp to the back of the list, and temp becomes temp -> next. ie temp goes only to the 2,3,4 rd node and not to the newly added node right?